# jQuery contains not working

Tags: jquery, contains

Is there something wrong with the code below it just won't work, no errors?

```
var select_value = $("#cart-image").attr('alt');

if ($("select_value:contains('Aqua')")) { keyword = "aqua"; };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While all the other answers are correct, they forget to mention that you **can** use jQuery for this. There is the [Attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
if ($("#cart-image[alt*=Aqua]").length) keyword = "aqua";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using jQuery to do something that it is neither designed for nor capable of.  Use Javascript's native functions to search strings for substrings:

```
if (select_value.indexOf('Aqua') > -1) {
    keyword = 'aqua';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The double quotes are making jQuery interpret the "select_value" as a string, rather than the variable.

try

```
if (select_value.indexOf('Aqua') != -1) { keyword = "aqua"; };
```

Answer (score 0):

.attr() returns a string, not a DOM element